# Go channel write ordering guarantees

Tags: go, concurrency

Given the following code:

```golang
ch1 := make(chan struct{}, 1)
ch2 := make(chan struct{})
ready := make(chan struct{})
done := make(chan struct{})

go func() {
    close(ready)
    select {
    case <-ch1:
        fmt.Println("ch1")
    case <-ch2:
        fmr.Println("ch2")
    }
}()

<-ready

ch1 <- struct{}{}
close(ch2)

<-done
```

Is it guaranteed to always print "ch1"? Or is it possible that since the `ch1` is buffered and `ch2` is closed right after, the second `case` could run first?

And is there any reference to verify this behavior in the documentation / code?

Comment: The relevant reference is for  select statements: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements, where _” If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.”_. The channels are “written” in order, but you are concerned with which will be received from first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee that the second case may not occur.

While you are using channels - and channels are ideal for synchronizing two goroutines - you are manipulating two separate channels. So there is no guarantee that the main goroutine's write to an unbuffered `ch1` channel will immediately yield control over to the second goroutine's select statement.

The close of `ch2` may also occur before the scheduler yields control to other goroutines - and then a `select` with two possible paths, will be chosen at random.

[Anectodal evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457790/golang-channel-write-ordering-guarantees) may be tempting to believe, but will lead to dangerous assumptions under different load conditions.

---

Looking at an early doc for the [Go Scheduler Design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TTj4T2JO42uD5ID9e89oa0sLKhJYD0Y_kqxDv3I3XMw/edit) will not be of much help as the implementation details of the schedule will literally change from release to release of the `Go` language.

In closing, coordination between the two independent channels is needed to make any guarantees of the processing order.

Comment: What if I ensure that the goroutine is already running *before* I do the channel write / close? Would this make a difference? E.g by using a waitgroup which is done once the goroutine starts up?

Comment: @shmth that won't matter. It's impossible to guarantee that the `select` will unblock immediately when `ch1` is written to. Meanwhile `ch2` might trigger already, and the `select` will unblock with both events triggered. Then it's up to the implementation to invoke both case handlers, in implementation-defined order.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to ch1 will not immediately cause the select operation to continue. The goroutine can be scheduled after the channel write or after the close operation so both cases have a chance to run. If ch1 was unbuffered then write operation would only happen after channel read so the program would always print ch1.

Comment: What if I ensure that the goroutine is already running *before* I do the channel write / close? Would this make a difference? E.g by using a waitgroup which is done once the goroutine starts up?

Comment: It would not make a difference.